# Ignore a global response assertion in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, assertion

Assume the structure below:

```
Thread Group
      -Simple Controller
                   -Global Response Assertion
                   -Http Sampler1
                   -Http Sampler2
                   -Http Sampler3
                   -Http Sampler4
                    etc
```

So the global response assertion will work on all the samplers below it. However, I need a way for a specific sampler to ignore the global assertion so for example i want HTTP sampler4 not to be asserted by the global assertion and to completely ignore it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can sampler4 be always successful?

Comment: no, I would like it to ignore the global assertions and give it its own assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have `beanshell` in tags my expectation is that your `Global Response Assertion` is a [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion). If so - you can "ignore" the `Http Sampler4` as follows:

```
if (SampleResult.getSampleLabel().equals("Http Sampler4")) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // your "global assertion" logic here 
}
```

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter version 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) in JMeter so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) on next available opportunity.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange your structure so that the response assertion isn't in the same level for the HTTP sampler that you don't want to have assertion on it, like below.

```
Thread Group
  -Simple Controller
               -Global Response Assertion
               -Http Sampler1
               -Http Sampler2
               -Http Sampler3
  -Simple Controller
               -Http Sampler4
  -Simple Controller
               -Global Response Assertion
               -Http Sampler5
               -Http Sampler6
               -Http Sampler7
                etc
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer however i am looking for a way to do this whilst keeping the existing structure. maybe its possible to do using a beanshell script or something?

Comment: Maybe you can replace your response assertion with a beanshell assertion, then maybe yes, otherwise i don't think its possible.